# KNP Paginator shows Invalid item per page number error in Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, binary, uuid, paginator

It was working till today. Entire application was bugless, until yesterday I tried to implement UUID as a binary type. So I first used, ramsey UUID, later tried a symfony bundle, as they add it recently, upgraded composer, installed new orm, and lastly, installed ramsey/uuid-binary, my application at last working.

But from minute to minute I started noticing a bunch of problems. First one was, need to add 'uuid_binary' type to parameter in QB. Later when I was searching by entity in my own queries I needed to past not an entity but entity->getId()!

And lastly, and this is a question, paginator broke down and I don't know why...

This is the error:

> Invalid item per page number. Limit: 10 and Page: 0, must be positive non-zero integers

Error is on 525 which is /* limit per page */ linie

This is mine controller:

```
        /**
     * @Route("thread/{threadid}/{threadname}", name="app_forum_thread_user", defaults={"threadname"=""})
     * @Security("is_granted('ROLE_USER')")
     */
    public function openThread(MainMenuService $mainMenuService, PaginatorInterface $paginator,
                               UserForumPostRepository $forumPostRepo, Request $request,
                               UserForumTopic $threadid, SessionInterface $session, EntityManagerInterface $em,
                               LoggerInterface $logger, PostsLikesRepository $like){
        $referer_array = explode('/', parse_url($request->headers->get('referer'))['path']);
        if ($referer_array[1] != 'thread' and $referer_array[2] != $threadid->getId()) {
            $views = $threadid->getViews();
            $threadid->setViews($views + 1);

            $em->persist($threadid);
            $em->flush();
        }

    

    //$pagination = $forumPostRepo->findPostsMinePagination($threadid->getId(), ($request->query->get('page'))? $request->query->get('page') : 0, ($session->get('plimit')) ? $session->get('plimit') : 10);
//
    

$query = $forumPostRepo->findPostsForThreadWithPagination($threadid->getId());
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $query, /* query NOT result */
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1), /*page number*/
            ($session->get('plimit') != null) ? $session->get('plimit') : 10 /*limit per page*/
        );
        $postsLikes = [];
        foreach ($pagination as $post){
            $wynik = $like->getPostLike($post->getId(), $this->getUser()->getId());

            $postsLikes[$post->getId()] = ($wynik)? 1 : 0 ;
        }
        $mainMenu = $mainMenuService->getMenu();

        return $this->render($_SERVER['DEFAULT_TEMPLATE'].'/forum/Thread_View.twig', [
            'title'=>'Forum - '.$_SERVER['APP_NAME'],
            'lang'=>'pl',
            'APP_NAME'=>$_SERVER['APP_NAME'],
            'logoSite'=>$_SERVER['SHOW_LOGO'],
            'navFooter'=>$_SERVER['NAV_FOOTER'],
            'footer'=>$_SERVER['FOOTER'],
            'pageName'=>"Forum",
            'MainMenu' => $mainMenu,
            'user'=>$this->getUser(),
            'profile'=>$threadid->getForum()->getCategory()->getIsItUserPrivateForum()->getUserAdmin(),
            'forumCre'=>$threadid->getForum()->getCategory()->getIsItUserPrivateForum(),
            'forum'=>$threadid->getForum(),
            'thread'=>$threadid,
            'posts_pagination'=>$pagination,
            'postsLikes'=>$postsLikes,
            'page'=> $request->query->get('page'),
            'theme'=>$this->theme

        ]);
        //return new Response('done');
    }
```

Use statements:

```
use App\Entity\Account;

use App\Entity\ForumCategory;
use App\Entity\PostsLikes;
use App\Entity\UserForumCategory;
use App\Entity\UserForumForum;
use App\Entity\UserForumPost;
use App\Entity\UserForumTopic;
use App\Entity\UserPrivateForum;
use App\Repository\AccountRepository;
use App\Repository\ForumCategoryRepository;
use App\Repository\ForumForumRepository;
use App\Repository\PostsLikesRepository;
use App\Repository\UserForumCategoryRepository;
use App\Repository\UserForumForumRepository;
use App\Repository\UserForumPostRepository;
use App\Repository\UserForumTopicRepository;
use App\Repository\UserPrivateForumRepository;
use App\Services\MainMenuService;
use App\Services\Validation;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Knp\Component\Pager\PaginatorInterface;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\KernelEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\SubRequestHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Subscriber\SlidingPaginationSubscriber;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
```

As you can see in the controller, mine paginator take session as the value. I tried to leave only 10 but I still get the error.

Please help

Comment: What is set to 0 in your paginator is `page` not `plimit` so it looks like a coercion error, you are getting something that can't be represented as a number. Can you check the raw value you are getting in that parameter? BTW, `$session->get()` also accepts a default value as a second parameter, so you could get rid of that ternary.